# Fluent Nhibernate: Not reading records from database that've been inserted via SqlServer Management Studio

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent

I am trying to realize a simple console program that creates some data and stores it into a db. The problem is that the program works only if I insert the records via code. If I try to read some records from a table that I created using SqlServer Management Studio, it's not working and read 0 records. Furthermore seems that the attempt to read this values delete somehow the data on the table. If I check SqlServer after the execution, the records previously inserted are gone. This the part when I perform the reading:

```
using(var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
{
    using(var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var DepartmentObject = InsertDepartment("IT", "962788700227");
        var firstEmployee = InsertEmployee("Jacopo", "disoccupated", DepartmentObject);
        var secondEmployee = InsertEmployee("Andrea", "programmatore", DepartmentObject);
        var thirdEmployee = InsertEmployee("Davide", "fashion-blogger", DepartmentObject);
        session.Save(DepartmentObject);
        session.Save(firstEmployee);
        session.Save(secondEmployee);
        session.Save(thirdEmployee);
        transaction.Commit();
        var elencoEmployee = session.Query<Employee>().ToList(); // this reading is working because I create the table and insert values via code
        var elencoTabTest = session.Query<TabTest>().ToList(); // this reading return a list of 0 elements but on the db there is a table named TabTest with 2 records
    }
}
```

The `InsertEmployee` and `InsertDepartment` functions only create an `Employee/Department` object setting its properties.

This is the class `TabTest` that should map the table that I want to read:

```
class TabTest
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Descrizione { get; set; }
}

class TabTestMap : ClassMap<TabTest>
{
    public TabTestMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Descrizione);
        Table("TabTest");
    }
}
```

If someone has some ideas please share.

Answer (score 0):

No, NHibernate isn't deleting your records when you just query for them. I can think of at least three possible explanations:

You are not showing the full code, so either you have some code elsewhere that deletes the rows, or truncates the table, or deletes and recreate the table.

Alternatively, you are using a transaction when you create the rows and failing to commit the transaction before you close it.

Another possibility is that the program is simply reading from a different table or a different database, due to configuration or mapping mistake.

Comment: I edited the code with the code present in the class that map the table, regarding the second point in this table I do nothing by code only the reading with Session.Query<TabTest>.

Comment: Nevertheless, "select isn't broken" (https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/). The piece of code you added doesn't prove anything (these pieces are still not a complete runnable program, so clearly you have more code). You need to review everything you do - are you really trying to read from the same table in the exact same database? Are you really sure you program or test script or whatever isn't reinitializing the database on each run? Turn on logging for NHibernate.SQL or use SQL Profiler to get the complete picture.